Non-text Contrast (Level AA) with input field background against a web page background
I have a question regarding the accessibility of this design and whether it complies with WCAG guidelines and success criteria. Below is an image of a set of input fields on a specific background:
NOTE: The double white outline on the third cell is a :focus on keyboard use (or tab press).

The white text against the input field background passes, as you can see here:

The blue line against the input field background also passes:

Our auditors have indicated that this input field does not meet accessibility standards due to insufficient contrast. However, their assessment is based on the contrast between the background color of the input field and the overall background of the webpage:

The text and the blue line within the input field do pass contrast requirements against both the input field background and the webpage background.
This design seems similar to the Basic TextField in Material UI, which is just a line with no background.
Could I get some advice on whether this assessment is accurate concerning WCAG "Non-text Contrast (Level AA)"? Specifically, do the background colours of the input field and the webpage need to meet contrast requirements, even if the main elements of the input field, such as the text and the blue line, already pass?

If the input always has text or an icon inside with enough contrast to the input's background color, the input meets the accessibility guideline. When the input is empty, it should have a background or border that has enough contrast with the adjacent background color.
As stated under success criterion 1.4.11: Non-text Contrast (Level AA):

This success criterion does not require that controls have a visual boundary indicating the hit area, but if the visual indicator of the control is the only way to identify the control, then that indicator must have sufficient contrast. If text (or an icon) within a button or placeholder text inside a text input is visible and there is no visual indication of the hit area then the Success Criterion is passed.


Thank you, I will run this past them and report back with their feedback.

If you switch the colors you're using for the elements you can pass the AA contrast. I'm assuming you're following the design guidelines from your client and that's why you're selecting those colors. Just use the white bg for the number container and change the text to your lighter gray. Also if you are working with a DSL it will be easy for the dev team to use the tokens for those colors.


Yes, that is correct, I'm using the current guidelines and colour palette, so trying my best to make it work without introducing new colours. But, that is a good shout.
